# Org mode headlines without bold font inside emacs

Tags: org-mode, fonts, emacs26

Is it possible to set org-mode to show the headlines inside emacs without bold font?

My emacs:

> * **Headline 1**    <-- This is bolded
>
> a paragraph       <-- This is not bolded
>
> **  **Headline 2**   <-- This is also bolded

I would like to have:

> * Headline 1        <-- Not bolded
>
> a paragraph        <-- Not bolded
>
> ** Headline 2      <-- Not bolded

Note: I have found a set-up that eliminates all fontification from the headlines:

```el
(setq org-level-color-stars-only t)
```

but I would like to keep colors and just eliminate boldness from the headlines at all levels.

Hopefully my question is understandable.

Thx!

Comment: When I open the recently released public version of Emacs 27 -- without any user-configuration (aka `emacs -Q`) -- and I go to the `*scratch*` buffer and type `M-x org-mode` and then on an empty line I type `* TODO [#A] testing one two three`, the only bold that I see is the word `TODO`.  If you do that same test -- without any user-configuration, aka `emacs -Q`, do you get the same result as me?  Perhaps you are using a theme that you installed which adds a `bold` spec to the `org-level-1` et seq. faces?

Comment: Using the same test in the comment above, I place my cursor anywhere on the words `testing one two three` and type `C-u C-x =` and then look in the `*Help*` buffer that opens up, I see the face at issue is `org-level-1` face.  If I place my cursor on the words `org-level-1` in the `*Help*` buffer and press the enter key, I see that the face is *inherited* from the `outline-1` face.  If I place my cursor on the words `outline-1` in the `*Help*` buffer and press the enter key, I see that the face is *inherited* from the `font-lock-function-name-face` face.  Repeat process, foreground is `Blue1`.

Answer (score 2):

@lawlist nailed it. It is a configuration of the theme. I am currently using [solarized](https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs).

I kinda of fixed my issue setting

`(setq solarized-use-variable-pitch nil)`

as it is suggested on the README. But I would like to point out that in my case, it removed all boldness rendering from the org file. For me it is enough, hence the answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you following the definition as @lawlist mentioned

you can see that it ultimately led to

`emacs/29.1/lisp/outline.el`

```
(defface outline-1
  '((t :inherit font-lock-function-name-face))
  "Level 1.")
```

the following will customize the font weight to normal instead of bold

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(outline-1 ((t (:extend t :weight normal))))
 '(outline-2 ((t (:extend t :weight normal))))
 '(outline-3 ((t (:extend t :weight normal))))
 '(outline-4 ((t (:extend t :weight normal))))
 '(outline-5 ((t (:extend t :weight normal))))
 '(outline-6 ((t (:extend t :weight normal))))
 '(outline-7 ((t (:extend t :weight normal))))
 '(outline-8 ((t (:extend t :weight normal)))))
```

Comment: This will affect all outlines, not only org headlines.

Comment: correct, since org-mode inherits from outline mode

Answer (score 0):

You can customize org-level faces:

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(org-level-1 ((t (:inherit outline-1 :weight normal))))
 '(org-level-2 ((t (:inherit outline-2 :weight normal))))
 '(org-level-3 ((t (:inherit outline-3 :weight normal))))
 '(org-level-4 ((t (:inherit outline-4 :weight normal))))
 '(org-level-5 ((t (:inherit outline-5 :weight normal))))
 '(org-level-6 ((t (:inherit outline-6 :weight normal))))
 '(org-level-7 ((t (:inherit outline-7 :weight normal))))
 '(org-level-8 ((t (:inherit outline-8 :weight normal)))))
```